# AES key storage management and salting in Python

Tags: python, encryption, storage, salt, secret-key

I am fairly new to data security implementation. I am writing a Python code that needs to encrypt clear text data. Currently, I am using the following AES encryption implementation to encrypt the data:

https://pythonprogramming.net/encryption-and-decryption-in-python-code-example-with-explanation/

I have two questions:

1) When using the encryption method, a random key is generated. That key needs to be used in the decryption method. I need to store the key in a file, so that it is accessible later. What is the proper method to secure the key stored in this file, and what format should this file have (is .txt OK, or should I use another format)? I keep reading methods to perform a second encryption to encrypt the first key, or similar things. But wouldn't the second key used for the second encryption be compromised then...?

Also, I want to avoid methods that use user-generated passwords to protect the encryption key. Maybe I should use a different encoding for each file that contains a different key? But I am not sure about how to do this…

2) I want to use salting so that same clear text values produce different data appearances. From what I understood, in order to perform the encryption, I need to use XOR for a random salt and the clear text, and then use the key to encrypt the result. At the moment of the decryption, I need to use the key to decrypt the string, and then use XOR with the same salt value that I used in the encryption so that I get the clear text in the end.

However, I don't quite understand how to generate the salt and how to store it. How can I make generate a random salt value that has the same length as the clear text that it is XOR-added with? And also, can I use the same encryption key to encrypt the salt value, since it is random, or doesn’t the salt value need any encryption at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. The bad news is that storing a key securely is very hard and device dependent. Many devices have some form of keystone, use that if available. Using a user entered passphrase each tine is the most secure method but generally to annoying for the user.
2. Random salts are obtained by making a call to a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator, the exact function is platform dependent, `arc4random` is such  a unix-like function. There are two methods, if you do not need to obtain the original value use a cryptographic hash such as HMAC. If you need to be able to reverse the operation use encryption such as AES.

There is a lot of information on cryptography and it is a large subject. My suggestion is to do a lot of studying, use a library methods of ask a question with information of what you are trying to accomplish.